# ManagementFactory from java.lang.management in Android

Tags: java, android, cpu-usage

Why java.lang.management isn't available in android? (At least i know that)

I need the use of "`getCurrentThreadCpuTime`" from "`ThreadMXBean`" class but I need `ManagementFactory` in order to retrieve it.

Is there an alternative to that class in android?

I need the cpu time spent by my thread.

Thanks in advance
  Leonardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android run on linux, so you can get the thread info from file /proc/$pid/stat.

You can read and analyse file /proc/$pid/stat to get the info you want.

```
public void getTotalMemory() {
String path = "/proc/$pid/stat";
String info="";
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fr, 8192);
    while ((info = localBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        //analyse 
        System.out.println("ThreadInfo:" + info);
    }
    // close...
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

[How to analyse thread status](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: Hi, /proc/cpuinfo does not show the information I need. I need to know how much cpu time my thread has spent, I don't need general cpu info.

Comment: OK, you can read and analyse file /proc/$pid/stat to get the info you want.

Comment: I guess get the info from linux is better than get it from JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it's a good solution for my problem. I just found this class "android.os.Process" that seems to do exactly what I need, I whould like to know you point of view about this.